# iOS WatchOS6 "Complication server connection invalidated."

Tags: apple-watch, ios13, watchos-6

I'm getting the WatchOS app crashing on 6.1. The error is listed below. I can not find any info on the error.

Complication server connection invalidated. You may lack the entitlement to look up the mach service, or there may have been an encoding error.

**How do I fix this?**